# Why do things decay in terms of base $e$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, radioactivity, half-life

For instance, why do radioactive elements follow some $e^{-x}$ relationship?  Why not $\pi^{-y}$ or some other numerical constant as the base?  Is there some fundamental reason for [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) being the base of an exponential relationship for physical phenomena like radioactive decay, scale heights in atmospheres, etc.?

Comment: But you can always change the base of an exponential function. That is, $e^x = 2^{x\log_2(e)}$.

Comment: For radioactivity, we typically don't use $e$ as the base. Base 2 is much more common ("half-life").

Comment: @JohnDoty - It is?  I was always taught it was an exponential relationship.  Ugh... perhaps I need a refund for my degrees ;P

Comment: @honeste_vivere "Half life" comes from the decay constant that naturally appears in base 2.

Comment: @honeste_vivere It *is* an exponential relationship. We could just as well use $e$ as the base. I don't know why it's customary to use 2 for radioactivity.

Comment: @John We use both for radioactivity, base 2 for the half-life, base e for the mean lifetime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#Mean_lifetime Eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_neutron_decay

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't think I've ever seen mean lifetimes of isotopes tabulated. Of course, for a particular purpose, mean lifetime may be more useful, but it is trivially obtained from the half life.

Comment: @John Sure, we almost always use halflife with isotopes, and mean lifetime with particles. The neutron is unusual in that both are used, and it's not unusual for its mean lifetime to be mistakenly stated as its halflife.

Comment: @PM2Ring The OP was about "radioactive elements" [sic], not particles.

Answer (score 17):

In some sense, all bases are equivalent. If something decays as $\sim e^{-t/\tau}$, where $\tau$ is a decay constant, then it *also* decays as $\sim b^{-t/\tau_b}$ for any base $b$, where $\tau_b = \tau / \log_b e=\tau \ln b$ (which you can verify using properties of logs).

The reason we like to use base $e$ in physics is because it arises naturally in calculus. For example, $y(t) = y_0 e^{-t/\tau}$ is the solution to the differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = -\frac{y(t)}{\tau}
\end{equation}
with the initial condition $y(0)=y_0$. In other bases, you would have an extra conversion factor appearing in the equation.

In fact in other fields where doing calculus isn't as important, it is more common to use other bases that are considered more "intuitive", like $10$ or $2$.

Answer (score 14):

There's nothing special about $e$ except that it's convenient in the sense that $e^t$ is its own derivative.  The description of exponential decay arises from the model that the rate of change is proportional to the amount of stuff remaining, i.e.,
$$
\frac{dN}{dt} = -\gamma N\,,
$$
which is solved the most succinctly and easily by
$$
N(t) = N_0e^{-\gamma t}\,.
$$
However, we can change the base of the exponential to be anything we like, and we often *do* to get things like half-lives. That is,
$$
N(t) = e^{-\gamma t} = 2^{\log_2(e^{-\gamma t})}
=2^{-(\gamma\log_2(e))t}
\,.
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\pi^x = e^{ln(\pi)x} = e^y $$

You can always write it as a power of e

Comment: And of course $\log_a b = 1 / \log_b a$